# Using unitialized variables in Python

Tags: python, initialization, pylint

Background: I have a class modeling a chip with registers, the chip has a bunch of registers, one of them is a high temperature limit for the built-in temperature sensor.

I have the following:

```
class foo():
  def __init__(self):
    # does not set self._hiTemp!
    ...
  def setHiTemp(self, t):
    self._hiTemp = t
  def getHiTemp(self):
    return self._hiTemp
  def checkHiTemp(self):
    return self._temp > self._hiTemp
```

The reason that I don't declare `self._hiTemp` in the `__init__` is because the user may not care about the temp-sensing capabilities of the chip. The user can be using the chip in different ways, and there is no meaning in giving this variable a meaningless value. However, if the user tries to use `self._hiTemp` without first setting it, the error of using undeclared variables is much easier to debug/backtrace than some obscure error like comparing numbers and None (or in some case even no errors at all).

This is all going fine until I start pylint, and of course I get W0201: Attribute defined outside **init** just about everywhere. I'm just wondering if this style of coding is frowned upon, and if so, what the "Pythonic way" is.

Thanks

Comment: I'd store such properties in a dictionary instead of instance attributes, feels cleaner for me.

Comment: @leoluk What does a dict gain you here? Part of the beauty of dynamic languages like Python is that all objects are essentially glorified dictionaries in the first place.  See also `self.\_\_dict\_\_`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The way I'd do it is set it to `None` or some other sentinel value that doesn't occur 'in nature'.  Then for operations that require it to be set, use an `assert` to fail fast in case the caller is trying to use your object inappropriately.

```
def __init__(self):
    self._hiTemp = None

def checkHiTemp(self):
    assert self._hiTemp is not None, 'Why you no set _hiTemp before checking it?'
    return self._temp > self._hiTemp
```

Comment: Using `assert` is the wrong thing to do as it can be optimised out at run time by using the `-O` or `-OO` flags.  The correct way is to raise an exception as show by @John-La-Rooy below.

Answer (score 6):

Python's not Java, so don't write getters and setters like that. You can solve your problem like this

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, hiTemp=None):
        self._hiTemp = hiTemp

    @property
    def hiTemp(self):
        if self._hiTemp is None:
            raise AttributeError("You have not initialized hiTemp")
        return self._hiTemp

    @hiTemp.setter
    def hiTemp(self, value):
        self._hiTemp = value

    def checkHiTemp(self):
        return self._temp > self._hiTemp

foo=Foo()
foo.hiTemp = 50
print foo.hiTemp # Prints 50

foo=Foo(hiTemp=20)
print foo.hiTemp # Prints 20

foo=Foo()
print foo.hiTemp # Raises exception
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I can use properties (I do in most places in my code), but they are still in essence setters and getters. My question regarding the way uninitialized functions are handled still stands though.

Comment: @paper.cut, Yes they are, but the key difference is that in Python I can use attribute access until I find I _need_ a getter or setter and then I just need to change code inside the class. I don't need to go refactoring code everywhere. I'm not sure why you prefer joe's answer - this works the same way but the test is done automatically so I don't need to remember to do repeat the test each time I access the attribute

Comment: While your answer is also good, however properties is not something that I asked for. I know how properties work and I am using them, just that for this question I was specifically asking about initializing variables, so I simplified it to not using properties.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a particular attribute of the object to be set via a method, then there could always be reason for it be available in the initializer. You can just use `self._hiTemp=None` You are already declaring it as private by leading `_`, so users will understand as not to rely on that.

Answer (score 0):

It's customary to use the value `None` to mean no real value. You can initialize it to that in `__init__`. You might also use a meaningless value in this case, such as a negative number, and check for that in the `checkHiTemp` method, and raise a custom exception if used without a properly initialized value. That is an even more meaningful error.

Answer (score 0):

I think from the user's perspective it would be better to have a proper error message than an undeclared variable error. I would do:

```
def __init__(self):
    self._hiTemp = None

def setHiTemp(self, t):
    self._hiTemp = t

def getHitemp(self):
    if self._hiTemp is None:
        raise Exception('You need to setHiTemp() before using it.')
    else:
        return self._hiTemp

def checkHiTemp(self):
    if self._hiTemp is None:
        raise Exception('You need to setHiTemp() before using it.')
    else:
        return self._temp > self._hiTemp
```

Comment: yeap, you're totally correct. It'd be better to change it to "if self._hiTemp is not None:". =)

Comment: I suppose something like "HiTemp not set" is a lot less cryptic than "foo instance has no attribute '_hiTemp'". Although, I'd probably raise AttributeError or NameError rather than just the base Exception =)